# Laravel merge arrays inside an array

Tags: php, laravel

I have such result

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    0 => 3
    1 => 7
    2 => 8
    3 => 9
    4 => 10
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    0 => 216
  ]
]
```

And I want to have it like this:

```
array:6 [
    0 => 3
    1 => 7
    2 => 8
    3 => 9
    4 => 10
    5 => 216
]
```

**How should I change my code?**

```
$barcodes = [];
foreach($request->input('serials') as $serial)
{
    if(!empty($serial['barcode_id'])) {
        if($serial['amount'] > 1) {
            $barcodes[] = Barcode::where('sold', true)->take($serial['amount'])->pluck('id')->toArray(); // returned `0 => array:5 [`
        } else {
            $barcodes[] = Barcode::where('sold', true)->where('serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->orWhere('u_serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->pluck('id')->toArray(); // returned `1 => array:1 [`
        }
    }
}
dd($barcodes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

the solution was using `...` operator to merge my inside arrays

`array_merge(...$barcodes)` and that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in the loop:

```
$barcodes = [];
foreach($request->input('serials') as $serial)
{
    if(!empty($serial['barcode_id'])) {
        if($serial['amount'] > 1) {
            $barcodes = array_merge($barcodes, Barcode::where('sold', true)->take($serial['amount'])->pluck('id')->toArray());
        } else {
            $barcodes = array_merge($barcodes, Barcode::where('sold', true)->where('serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->orWhere('u_serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->pluck('id')->toArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more laravelish way;

```
//Bring in Arr facade
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
//Then
Arr::flatten($barcodes);
```